# TFS Installation

Tags: tfs, installation

I setup TFS today on my machine and whenever I try to go to the web access it keeps asking me for a username and password. It also prompts me for one when I try to administer security in the application tier.

I didn't select a username and password when I set this up and I tried my machines username and password but it won't work. To top it off, my machine does not have a password and it keeps telling me i have to enter a password.

Is there a default password or login that I need to know about?

Comment: Is this Win7?  I ask, because you mention you don't have a password.  I don't have an environment to confirm, but you'll likely need a password to support integrated auth which is used by TFS.

Comment: What browser? Some Chrome and FF browsers need an additional bit configured to work with NTLM auth.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm having a similar problem in Windows 8. I was unable to get it to work in Chrome (my default browser) but I was able to sign in through IE 10 using the same Live ID credentials used to log into the PC.

Answer (score 0):

TFS only works with accounts that have a password.

Answer (score 0):

Also, TFS only works with domain accounts, not machine accounts.

Comment: That's actually untrue. TFS can be installed in workgroup mode, as long as it's installed on a single machine.